# How to start chrome extension in background on windows startup

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension installed from chrome store. I am looking for a way to start this extension in the background on windows startup or user login.
I need it running before the user starts browsing. I have tried to use "chrome.exe --no-startup-window" or "chrome.exe --headless".
Chrome processes start but immediately closes.

Comment: You need to add `"background"` to `"permissions"` in manifest.json and make sure "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" is enabled in browser options. See also [Google Chrome Packaged App - run at system startup](//stackoverflow.com/a/17883115)

Comment: Thanks, but this is relevant when chrome was opened at least once, right? I am looking for a way to start it before chrome is opened.

Comment: Why "but"? Did you try and it didn't work? AFAIK it will start before the browser.